# How to add plugins to nodeos when Docker is used?

Tags: nodeos, docker

I have used docker to install EOS and to run nodeos. Here are the containers -

```
docker container ls
```

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
39d42adc46cc        eosio/eos           "/opt/eosio/bin/keos…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours                                                          docker_keosd_1
7af14e3c1b23        eosio/eos           "/opt/eosio/bin/node…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9876->9876/tcp   docker_nodeosd_1
```

I need to add a plugin for history, for example - https://eosio-nodeos.readme.io/docs/history_api_plugin -

```
# config.ini
plugin = eosio::chain_plugin
plugin = eosio::mongo_db_plugin


# nodeos startup params
--plugin eosio::chain_plugin --plugin eosio::mongo_db_plugin
```

I guess I could use docker-compose down, change config.ini (and Dockerfile), and then up but I am unsure what impact that would have on persistent data and also that is not very convenient.

Is there a preferred way to add plugins to a docker container running nodeos? On a related point, I will need to add more nodes, so I assume there is an easy way to add more nodes also using docker, is that starting  new containers (or does that mean defining a service in docker)?

Here is the Dockerfile -

```
FROM eosio/builder as builder
ARG branch=master
ARG symbol=SYS

RUN git clone -b $branch https://github.com/EOSIO/eos.git --recursive \
    && cd eos && echo "$branch:$(git rev-parse HEAD)" > /etc/eosio-version \
    && cmake -H. -B"/tmp/build" -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWASM_ROOT=/opt/wasm -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ \
       -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/build  -DSecp256k1_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local -DBUILD_MONGO_DB_PLUGIN=true -
DCORE_SYMBOL_NAME=$symbol \
    && cmake --build /tmp/build --target install && rm /tmp/build/bin/eosiocpp


FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install openssl ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder /tmp/build/bin /opt/eosio/bin
COPY --from=builder /tmp/build/contracts /contracts
COPY --from=builder /eos/Docker/config.ini /
COPY --from=builder /etc/eosio-version /etc
COPY --from=builder /eos/Docker/nodeosd.sh /opt/eosio/bin/nodeosd.sh
ENV EOSIO_ROOT=/opt/eosio
RUN chmod +x /opt/eosio/bin/nodeosd.sh
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib
VOLUME /opt/eosio/bin/data-dir
ENV PATH /opt/eosio/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start nodeos with this command, your plugin comes in bolded area.

> docker run --rm --name eosio -d -p 8888:8888 -p 9876:9876 -v
>   /tmp/work:/work -v /tmp/eosio/data:/mnt/dev/data -v
>   /tmp/eosio/config:/mnt/dev/config eosio/eos-dev  /bin/bash -c "nodeos
>   -e -p eosio **--plugin eosio::wallet_api_plugin --plugin eosio::wallet_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin
>   eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin
>   eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin** -d
>   /mnt/dev/data --config-dir /mnt/dev/config
>   --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console --http-validate-host=false"

Comment: That is using docker run? I thought EOS recommended using docker-compose up and Dockerfile for docker build. If we use run then we need to code more. Also I understand we can just docker-compose down and change the files and then up. But really I want to be able to change EOS when it is running. Otherwise we need to down and up everytime we have a plugin to add.

Comment: BTW for that reason I installed EOS locally :)

Comment: I tried that. But it took ages. Docker is a quick install.

Comment: It took 25-40 minutes on my machine.

Comment: Really? It took me far longer. Maybe it is dependent on memory etc; also OS.